# Fischer Esterification and Dean Stark

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why is it Impossible do use a Dean Stark Montage if our reactives are more volatile than the mixture (H20 + Toluene for example)

Answer (score 2):

Because the reactants distill over into the toluene phase of the collection arm, where they cool down and there is no catalytic acid so the reactions stops. The result is a concentrated toluene solution of the reactants in the collection arm.